# Show that if $B \subseteq Y$, then $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two nonempty sets and consider a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$. Show that if $B \subseteq Y$, then $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$.

My attempt:

Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(B))$. Then there is a $x \in f^{-1}(B)$, and then a $y' \in B$. But $y'=y$, since $f(f^{-1}(y')) \neq y$ is impossible (but why...?). Hence $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subset B$
Next, let $y \in B$. Then there is a $x \in f^{-1}(B)$, and then a $y' \in f(x)$. But $y'=y$, since $f(f^{-1}(y')) \neq y$ is impossible (but why is this...?). Hence $B \subset f(f^{-1}(B))$.
Together, $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$

I regard this proof as flawed, at least incomplete. Why must $f(f^{-1}(y'))=y$? If $f$ would be a bijective, the inverse function $f^{-1}$ would be defined and the composition would be the "identity function"... but the function is not necessarily injective and surjective.

I also realise that making the assumption that $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ actually is what we wanted to show in the first place... :) So, this is not a proof, I realise.

Perhaps I could make an assumption that $f(f^{-1}(y))\neq y$ and see that this would lead to a contradiction, in some way...

Comment: The claim is false: the true identity is $f(f^{-1}(B))=f(X)\cap B$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, could you explain that? It's from my text book, so that would be interesting... I'm not saying you are incorrect, I'm a n00b, but the exercise is from published literature...

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think the textbook assume that $f(X) = Y$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn I can't assume what is not written.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Hmm, I thought it is a common assumption

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn Not in the slightest. Would you say $\exp :\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is commonly considered false?

Comment: As I understand, the statement $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is not the same as $f(X)=Y$, The latter is a identity, meaning all of $X$ is sent to $Y$, while the former means that $f$ sends $X$ to $Y$ but perhaps not everything in $X$.